# Exercise sources for an engineering freshman

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation, online-resources

I'm an engineering freshman and I want to know good sources for exercises only that have a variety of different problems on subjects with answers, Any recommendations would be appreciated for the following topics :

**(1) Antiderivatives or The Indefinite Integral (The Indefinite Integral, Properties of The Indefinite Integral, Integration by Substitution, Integrals Involving Quadratic Expressions, Miscellaneous Substitutions).**

**(2) Techniques of Integration (integration by Parts, Reduction Formulas, Trigonometric and Hyperbolic Integrals, Trigonometric and Hyperbolic Substitutions, Integration of Rational Functions by Partial Fractions).**

**(3) The Definite Integral (The Definite Integral as a Limit to Riemann Sums, The Fundamental Theorems of Calculus (Part (1) - Part (2)), Properties of The Definite Integral, Some Important Integrals, Some Important Theorems, Improper Integrals (Integrals with Infinite Limits of Integration Integrals with Discontinuous Integrands), - Numerical Integration (Trapezoidal Rule, Simpson's Rule)).**

**(4) Applications of The Definite Integral (Area between Curves, Solids of Revolution (Volumes by Circular Disk - Volumes by Washer Technique Volumes by Cylindrical Shell Technique), Arc Length, Area of a Surface of Revolution).**

**(5) Partial Derivatives (Directional Derivatives, Tangent Plane and Normal Line, Critical Points of Functions of Several Variables).**

Comment: Have you done all the exercises in your calculus book?

Comment: Although it’s not marketed as a giant book of exercises, I used [Gradshteyn’s Table of Integrals and Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradshteyn_and_Ryzhik) as exactly that for years. Plus, it’s free! ^_^

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes most of the question ideas on topics I've taken but it's always better to open minded check more resources.